# nodejs why EPIPE thrown when running `process.stdin.write` on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, process, operating-system

how to write some data to current process's own stdin on windows.
i tried it but got an EPIPE error on windows (but mac works well), why/how windows throws the EPIPE error ?

[image: mac]
[image: windows]